# How to access every element of a multi-dimensional Python list through a loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, matrix, input

```
import re
def get_number(element):
    re_number = re.match("(\d+\.?\d*)", element)

    if re_number:
        return float(re_number.group(1))
    else:
        return 1.0

def getvalues(equation):
    elements = re.findall("([a-z0-9.]+)", equation)
    return [get_number(element) for element in elements]


eqn = []
eqn_no = int(raw_input("Enter the number of equations: "))

for i in range(eqn_no):
    eqn.append(getvalues(str(raw_input("Enter Equation %d: " % (i+1)))))
print "Main Matrix: "
for i in range((eqn_no)):
    for j in range((eqn_no+1)):
        print "\t%f" %(eqn[i][j]),
    print
print
equation=[]
equation=eqn
for k in range((eqn_no-1)):
    for i in range((k+1),eqn_no):
        for j in range((eqn_no+1)):
            if(eqn[i][j]!=0):
                eqn[i][j]=eqn[i][j]-(eqn[k][j]*(equation[i][k]/eqn[k][k]))



    print "Matrix After %d step: " %(k+1)
    for i in range(eqn_no):
            for j in range((eqn_no+1)):
                print "\t%f"%(eqn[i][j]),
                equation[i][j]=eqn[i][j];

            print
    print
```

for input:

```
25x+5y+z=106.8
64x+8y+z=177.2
144x+12y+z=279.2

output is:

Main Matrix: 
    25.000000   5.000000    1.000000    106.800000
    64.000000   8.000000    1.000000    177.200000
    144.000000  12.000000   1.000000    279.200000

Matrix After 1 step: 
    25.000000   5.000000    1.000000    106.800000
    0.000000    8.000000    1.000000    177.200000
    0.000000    12.000000   1.000000    279.200000

Matrix After 2 step: 
    25.000000   5.000000    1.000000    106.800000
    0.000000    8.000000    1.000000    177.200000
    0.000000    0.000000    1.000000    279.200000

But it should be like

Main Matrix: 
    25.000000   5.000000    1.000000    106.800000
    64.000000   8.000000    1.000000    177.200000
    144.000000  12.000000   1.000000    279.200000

Matrix After 1 step: 
    25.000000   5.000000    1.000000    106.800000
    0.000000    -4.80000    -1.56000    -96.208000
    0.000000    -16.8000    -4.76000    -335.968000

Matrix After 2 step: 
    25.000000   5.000000    1.000000    106.800000
    0.000000    -4.80000    -1.56000    -96.208000
    0.000000    0.000000    0.699999    0.759981
```

Does anyone have any idea why the hell on earth is this happening? Why the zero parts are changing and others aren't? I have done this code in c++ and it works there perfectly but here I'm facing many problem. Maybe I'm newbie to python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: how to iterate over list of list while iterating over each item in each nested list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648662/python-how-to-iterate-over-list-of-list-while-iterating-over-each-item-in-each)

Comment: Not at all. that code was using pre-defined value. I am using user-defined input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
def get_number(element):
    re_number = re.match("(-?\d+\.?\d*)", element)

    if re_number:
        return float(re_number.group(1))
    else:
        return 1.0

def getvalues(equation):
    elements = re.findall("(-?[a-z0-9.]+)", equation)
    return [get_number(element) for element in elements]


eqn = []
eqn_no = int(raw_input("Enter the number of equations: "))

for i in range(eqn_no):
    eqn.append(getvalues(str(raw_input("Enter Equation %d: " % (i+1)))))

print

for line in eqn:
    print "|" + "  ".join(["%3.1f" % value for value in line]) + "|"
```

For example:

```
Enter the number of equations: 2
Enter Equation 1: x+2y=3
Enter Equation 2: 4x+5y=6

|1.0  2.0  3.0|
|4.0  5.0  6.0|
```

This should also work for something like `4.3x+6.7y=8`

Comment: How about taking input from user? Every time I try to give input, I get some error. I want to give input for 'n' number of inputs where n will also take input.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include your existing input stages, hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure what format you want, but I have updated the script to give you an idea to play with yourself.

Comment: You are welcome. When you are happy with the final answer, don't forget you can accept it to get your Scholar badge.

Comment: I am now facing another problem. some of the elements aren't changing as the way they should be. Can you help me with it? I have updated my code.

Comment: It's  probably best to start a new question. Then others will help too.

Comment: Added a new question. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461840/nested-list-doesnt-work-properly

Comment: @ Martin Evans , Your re function can't hold negative value. It automatically converts them into positive. See the ideone link: http://ideone.com/FQF7Hb

Comment: I've added a change to the regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks @ Martin Evans .