# Nested list doesn't work properly

Tags: python, input, nested-lists

```
import re
def get_number(element):
    re_number = re.match("(\d+\.?\d*)", element)

    if re_number:
        return float(re_number.group(1))
    else:
        return 1.0

def getvalues(equation):
    elements = re.findall("([a-z0-9.]+)", equation)
    return [get_number(element) for element in elements]


eqn = []
eqn_no = int(raw_input("Enter the number of equations: "))

for i in range(eqn_no):
    eqn.append(getvalues(str(raw_input("Enter Equation %d: " % (i+1)))))
print "Main Matrix: "
for i in range((eqn_no)):
    for j in range((eqn_no+1)):
        print "\t%f" %(eqn[i][j]),
    print
print
equation=[]
equation=eqn
for k in range((eqn_no-1)):
    for i in range((k+1),eqn_no):
        for j in range((eqn_no+1)):
            if(eqn[i][j]!=0):
                eqn[i][j]=eqn[i][j]-(eqn[k][j]*(equation[i][k]/eqn[k][k]))



    print "Matrix After %d step: " %(k+1)
    for i in range(eqn_no):
            for j in range((eqn_no+1)):
                print "\t%f"%(eqn[i][j]),
                equation[i][j]=eqn[i][j];

            print
    print
```

for input:

```
25x+5y+z=106.8
64x+8y+z=177.2
144x+12y+z=279.2
```

output is:

```
Main Matrix: 
    25.000000   5.000000    1.000000    106.800000
    64.000000   8.000000    1.000000    177.200000
    144.000000  12.000000   1.000000    279.200000

Matrix After 1 step: 
    25.000000   5.000000    1.000000    106.800000
    0.000000    8.000000    1.000000    177.200000
    0.000000    12.000000   1.000000    279.200000

Matrix After 2 step: 
    25.000000   5.000000    1.000000    106.800000
    0.000000    8.000000    1.000000    177.200000
    0.000000    0.000000    1.000000    279.200000
```

But it should be like

```
Main Matrix: 
    25.000000   5.000000    1.000000    106.800000
    64.000000   8.000000    1.000000    177.200000
    144.000000  12.000000   1.000000    279.200000

Matrix After 1 step: 
    25.000000   5.000000    1.000000    106.800000
    0.000000    -4.80000    -1.56000    -96.208000
    0.000000    -16.8000    -4.76000    -335.968000

Matrix After 2 step: 
    25.000000   5.000000    1.000000    106.800000
    0.000000    -4.80000    -1.56000    -96.208000
    0.000000    0.000000    0.699999    0.759981
```

First of all this is a partial code for solving root of n number of equations using Naive Guass elemination method. Does anyone have any idea why the hell on earth is this happening? Why the zero parts are changing and others aren't? I have done this code in c++ and it works there perfectly but here I'm facing many problem. Maybe I'm newbie to python. I'm using python 2.7.....

Comment: what is this supposed to be doing? in plain english ...

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the logic of this program.  What is the purpose?

Comment: ahhh its linear algebra I think now I am starting to make sense of it

Comment: Why do you repeatedly use double brackets to call `range`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is the assignment `equation = eqn`. Since `eqn` is a list, it is a mutable and thus passed as a reference, when you assign a mutable, the variable actually contains a pointer to that object. This means that `equation` and `eqn` are the same list.

You should

```
from copy import deepcopy
equation = deepcopy(eqn)
```

You need `deepcopy` instead of `copy` because you have a list of lists, also the inner list needs to be copied.

Comment: I would have a list of matrix iterations and append each iteration to that list, so we don't have to have multiple objects holding iterations.
iterationList = list() then iterationList.append(eqn)

Comment: Your block "from copy import deepcopy   equation = deepcopy(eqn)" doesn't work. It gets syntax error. Please edit this block. I'm using python 2.7....

Comment: @AhashanAlamSojib It actually works, did you write it all in one line?

Comment: No,  @Oberix . I'm giving ideone link of this code. See for yourself.  http://ideone.com/eQjHFe

Comment: @AhashanAlamSojib Ok, I got it: either you `import copy; equation = copy.deepcopy(eqn)` or `from copy import deepcopy; equation = deepcopy(eqn)`

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
equation=eqn
```

doesn't do what you think it does. Try this instead:

```
import copy
equation=copy.deepcopy(eqn)
```

Python assignment isn't a copy operation, but rather a binding operation. The line you have means "*bind the name `equation` to the same object to which `eqn` is currently bound.*"

Your algorithm requires that `equation` and `eqn` are distinct objects.

Comment: Your block "import copy
equation=copy.deepcopy(eqn)" doesn't work. It gets syntax error. Please edit this block. I'm using python 2.7....